# Winsock2 non-local refused

Tags: ip, winsock2

(I have not put code in this question since the actual code probably doesn't matter here. If you say it does though then I can edit the question later to put it in.)

I'm new to using winsock2 or any other networking API for that matter. I have a very simple server application and client application in which the server sends a string to the client and then disconnects.

The applications work fine when I use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` as the `inet_addr()` argument, but when I use my "real" IP, the client application just gets `WSAECONNREFUSED` and the server doesn't see it. I made sure that the port was the same for both applications and that also the protocol was the same.

[Edit] I have come back to this issue after abandoning networking for a while. I think this may actually have something to with the fact I am using a router, and not something in my code.

Answer (score 1):

`WSAECONNREFUSED` is an active refusal of the connection by the peer or by an intermediate firewall. If it was the peer who issued it, it means you got the IP address or the port wrong, or else you got it right but the server isn't actually running; anyway, nothing is listening at that IP:port. If it was the firewall, adjust it.

Did you use `htons()` on the port number?

Comment: Using a network analyzer (tcpdump, wireshark, etc.) on either or both of the hosts may reveal what the root of the problem is.

Comment: Yes I did use `htons()`, and I used my own IP while the server was running (and I checked by using `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` to make sure the server worked properly). I did add a rule to my firewall to always allow in and out on that port (and moved the rule to the top) but it's the first time I've ever used that feature of the firewall so I'm not sure if I did it correctly.

Comment: Also the port shouldn't matter at all since I didn't change anything about the port on either the client or server between trying with the local address and then using my 'real' IP.

Answer (score 0):

`inet_addr()` only works with IP address strings, you have to use `gethostbyname()` or `getaddrinfo()` to resolve `localhost` or any other hostname string to an IP address.

`WSACONNREFUSED` means the connection was actively refused on the remote end that you are trying to connect to.

If the server machine is refusing, that means either there is no socket listening on the requested IP:Port, or that there is one but its queue of pending client connections is full so it cannot accept a new connection at that moment.

If a router is refusing, that usually means the router is not configured to forward inbound connections for the requested IP:Port to a machine on the router's network.  If you have a server running behind a router and are trying to connect to it using the router's public IP address, then the router has to be setup for port forwarding.

If a firewall is refusing, that usually means the requested port is not open.

Either way, there is no way for the client to know in code why the connection was refused.  All it can do is wait for a period of time and then try again.